# Liferay 6.1 PortletSession ID changed in iframe in Google Chrome when I link to another page

Tags: google-chrome, session, liferay, liferay-6

I'm creating PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE attributes. When I embed the portlet in an iframe, when I change location to other page (inside my domain) with location.href, the PorletSession Id has changed and all the attributes are lost.

If i don't use iframe (widget url directly in browser) is working fine.

This looks like block from Google Chrome, because is working fine in Opera. And I guess that this was working fine time ago.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

The last release of Liferay 6.1.x (CE) was in 2013, and even the enterprise-supported version is out of service by now. 2013 was a time when browsers were a lot more relaxed on sharing information between different sites and what you implemented back then might have worked.

Session storage is something that's discouraged anyway - and very often there are better and more scalable ways to solve the problem someone intended to solve through session storage.

Given the time that your version of the platform is out of service by now: It's time to upgrade. By now you won't get any security issues fixed, let alone other help in case you should run into other issues (like this).

And with regards to the implied question of "how do I make this work again?" (note: you're not asking any question, just state what you observe):

Start with thinking back of the underlying *business* problem that you tried to solve in the ancient past. You can't use the current iframe technique any more due to changed browser behavior, so think back of *what* you wanted to solve, *not how* you wanted to solve it back then.